# jQuery append HTML contains onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I used jQuery to append content to a div, and the content contains ondrop, on dragover, and ondragstart events? How can I handle the events properly, the following does not work:

```
<script>
    var html = "<div id="dragon_id" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
            ...</div>";
    $("myDiv").append(html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes within the double quotes otherwise the double quotes will break:

```
<script>
    var html = "<div id='dragon_id' ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>
            ...</div>";
    $("myDiv").append(html);
</script>
```

Comment: This does indeed work with the code you have posted. If it doesn't, something else is going wrong elsewhere and, if that's the case, please update and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```js
            var html = "<div id='dragon_id' ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>OK</div>";
            $("#myDiv").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I hope to help.

Comment: You can run code to see that this work. If your code is different please post.